# Selecting the value of a third variable by matching two or more variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to populate a sparse matrix by matching the name of each item in **df$Data_ID** with the column names of the **sparse** matrix created below and then selecting the corresponding value of **df$Response**.

```
df <- data.frame(
Data_ID=c("Item_1","Item_3","Item_5","Item_7","Item_4","Item_6","Item_3","Item_2","Item_3"),
Response= c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
)

sparse <- matrix(NA, 9, 7)

colnames(sparse) <- c("Item_1","Item_2","Item_3","Item_4","Item_5","Item_6","Item_7")
```

I'd like to generate a matrix like this, selecting the valid response **df$Response** only and keeping the remaining non-matching values as NA:

[image]

It seems quite simple, but I tried several for loops and none returned what I need. Could you please help me with this? Many thanks

Comment: If you actually want a sparse matrix as output, another alternative is `xtabs(Response ~ seq_len(nrow(df)) + Data_ID, data=df, sparse=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

We create a row/column index with the sequence of rows from 'df' and `match`ing the 'Data_ID' and the column names of 'sparse' to create a two column row/column index matrix, get the corresponding elements of 'sparse' and assign it with 'Response' column of 'df'

```
sparse[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
      match(df$Data_ID, colnames(sparse)))] <- df$Response
```

-output

```
sparse
#      Item_1 Item_2 Item_3 Item_4 Item_5 Item_6 Item_7
# [1,]      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# [2,]     NA     NA      0     NA     NA     NA     NA
# [3,]     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
# [4,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1
# [5,]     NA     NA     NA      0     NA     NA     NA
# [6,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      0     NA
# [7,]     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
# [8,]     NA      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
# [9,]     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

---

If the OP wanted a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(sparse))) sparse[i, df$Data_ID[i]] <- df$Response[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `for` loop that does what you asked, since this is tagged `for-loop`:

```
matched <- match(df$Data_ID,colnames(sparse))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  sparse[i,matched[i]] <- df$Response[i]
}
```

The `match` function figures out which column to place the Response in.

```
sparse
      Item_1 Item_2 Item_3 Item_4 Item_5 Item_6 Item_7
 [1,]      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [2,]     NA     NA      0     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [3,]     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
 [4,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1
 [5,]     NA     NA     NA      0     NA     NA     NA
 [6,]     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      0     NA
 [7,]     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [8,]     NA      0     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
 [9,]     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might be making this more complicated than it needs to be.  Basically, you are trying to convert long data to wide data.  This can be accomplished with the `dcast()` function in the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(Data_ID=c("Item_1","Item_3","Item_5","Item_7","Item_4","Item_6","Item_3","Item_2","Item_3"),Response= c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1))
df[,"rows"]<-c(1:nrow(df))

sparse<-dcast(df,rows~Data_ID, value.var="Response")
sparse<-as.matrix(sparse[,-1]) #Just to get rid of the column title "Row" and to convert to a matrix format
print(sparse)
```

`dcast()` takes a dataframe, in your case `df`, and then a formula for how to "cast" the dataframe to wide format. To the left of the `~` are the variables you want as rows, and to the right are the variables you want as columns.  The `value.var=` argument determines what values populate each row/column combination.